# Change Disk Type Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have azure ml , I created compute for learning.
Cost for instance is 2-5usd with my use. But cost for p10(premium SSD) Disk 17usd.

I don't know how change it because its not appear in azure Disk and in ML studio i cant find option for manage storage type for compute.

Some one know how change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possible way to change the compute disk type if you use the Azure ML compute cluster and compute instance. Only when you use the extra computer, you can manage the separate resources such as the disk, network, and so on. For example, you attach a VM as the target computer to the Azure ML. Then when you create the VM you can set the disk type with HDD.

Comment: This is such a major flaw in azure ml studio IMO. The conda envs take up 50GB of space out of the 120GB to start with so you're left with 1990s-style HDD sizes. Utter failure of microsoft to not be able to customize the base disk for ml compute instances, and I have no idea where to complain. Just screaming into the void

Comment: @wordsforthewise you could use a file share in AML workspace. https://vladiliescu.net/3-tips-for-aml-compute-instances/#3-theres-never-enough-storage-for-conda-envs

Comment: Yeah but fileshare is slow because it's over the network. I already figured out a solution - remove the default conda envs and use the /mnt drive, copy/pasting big data from it every time the machine boots/shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success from using `/dev/shm` to store files. `/mnt` was way too slow.